# How to get module name of active menu on joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I can get current menu title by this code :

`<?php
$active = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive();
echo $active->title;
?>`

But can I somehow get the menu module name?

Comment: I think you have to use `JModuleHelper` for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event you have multiple menus using 'mod_mainmenu' you could do something like this:

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule( 'mainmenu', 'ModuleTitle' );
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $module );
echo '</pre>';
```

That will get you what you're looking for I think.

You can also check up on the [JModuleHelper/getModule](http://docs.joomla.org/JModuleHelper/getModule) information in Joomla Docs - by studying that page you'll be able to do exactly what you want with little effort.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The following code use to put title in joomla

$document = JFactory::getDocument();

$document->setTitle('Page Title');